# java version in JAVA_HOME and PATH are mismatch

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, java-home, eclipse-neon

I have 02 questions :

1 - I try to run Eclipse neon in my Ubuntu 14.04 and i'm  getting this Error

[image]

I think this problem is linked to java version (Eclipse neon required java 8) ??

2 - So, I check my java version , take what i get

java -version

[image]

neon vi /etc/profile.d/java.sh

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is my problem, i'm setting java_home = java 8 but in PATH it's still java 7 !!!, What you think ? i want java -version = java 8

Thanks

Comment: Does `/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_20` actually exist?

Comment: yes
➜  ~ cd /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_20
➜  jdk1.8.0_20

Answer (score 1):

It seems like in your Path variable, the reference to Java 1.7 is given before Java 1.8.
When you run java -version, it search for bin directory in Path variable and as soon as it gets a reference, it returns the version. Try to remove /opt/java/jdk1.7.0_21/bin from your Path variable and I believe it will work after that. 
Hope this answer helps you

Comment: my path variable don't contain java 1.7
this is it : PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"

Comment: but ther's a script that change path to add java 1.7, like mine java_home to add a.8, but i don't get it

Comment: I can see in last picture, where you did "echo $PATH". The path is given /opt/java/jdk1.7.0_21

Comment: echo $PATH give you the generated path after all script that change it was runed, but at first it's value is in /etc/environment = < PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbi‌​n:/bin:/usr/games:/u‌​sr/local/games">

Answer (score 0):

It seems the the java.sh would do what you want: Setting the JAVA_HOME- and PATH-environment-variables.
Are you sure it is started, when you start java? Did you start it manually and test if it works then, yet?

Comment: this is my pbm, i'm setting java_home = java 8 but in PATH it's java 7 !!!

Comment: Either you have not executed the script which does:
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
Since then your PATH-variable should at least have both, the jdk7 and the jdk8-path (since your PATH already has the jdk7-path in it, and it doesnt get truncated out, if you don't do it yourself)
Or you didnt set your JAVA_HOME right.
Try setting your PATH manually: Take your current PATH, delete the JDK7-Path and add your JDK8-Path manually.

Comment: @zebiridjallil The script you run can potentially overwrite `JAVA_HOME` for the duration of the script.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , i want to know where's this script ? that overwrite mine

Answer (score 0):

When you run the script, I guess export cmd only changes the PATH in that shell and you might be running the eclipe from another shell. Also check eclipse.ini file for eclipse version.

Answer (score 0):

Well, many things to have in mind here.

First is... it doesnt matter what java_home you use, it will still look your path first! Your path is using java7! You should remove the java hardcoded from path and instead use the JAVA_HOME/bin in the path. Maybe you switch user when you modified the environment variables? **Also dont forget to export JAVA_HOME before export PATH!**

Second... You might have a system global java, but want to run eclipse with some other jre. Check your -vm setting in eclipse.ini (normally in /etc/eclipse.ini)

Add this top of your eclipse.ini

```
-vm
/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_20/bin/java
```

---

[From askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409111/export-path-doesnt-work-correctly) (regarding why PATH update doesnt work)

> There are a few places where you can define `$PATH`:
>
> `/etc/environment` is a plain text file (not a script) that affects all
>   users `~/.pam_environment` - the same thing but user-specific `bash` also
>   executes some scripts which can be used for modifying `$PATH`:
>
> `~/.profile` is executed for a login shell sessions (don't ask me what
>   it means :)
>
> `~/.bashrc` is executed for non login interactive shell
>   sessions
>
> `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bash.bashrc` are system wide
>   alternatives for `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc`
>
> I read somewhere that
>   `/etc/environment` is a recommended place for defining your `$PATH`. So I
>   usually use it. But your path is probably modified in one of the other
>   places.
>
> BTW, when you execute a command with `sudo`, I think it normally uses
>   `root` user's $PATH (and not the $PATH of your unprivileged user
>   account). So, ~/.pam_environment, `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` in `/root`
>   directory may also play a role.

Comment: my path dont contain Java hardcoded value, /etc/environment = < PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbi‌​‌​n:/bin:/usr/games:‌​/u‌​sr/local/games">

Comment: read this about PATH, and user specifics.. http://askubuntu.com/questions/409111/export-path-doesnt-work-correctly

Comment: my eclipse is running now, after that i add
-vm
/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_20/bin/java
it's OK now, but i already get the version msimatch problem in PATH/JAVA_HOME

Comment: I think you forget to export JAVA_HOME when setting to java 8, !! See my bold text, "Also dont forget to export JAVA_HOME before export PATH!"